# How to use google maps simple api on localhost

Tags: google-maps, localhost

I have requested a link for embedding google maps on my website on

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start
```

and have authorized everyone with the link to use it

```
Referers: Any referer allowed
https://code.google.com/apis/console/
```

but I still receive a

```
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized 
to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: 
Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console
```

Is there some other way to test my website locally with embedded google maps?

EDIT:
They say:

```
Easy embedding

Google Maps Embed API maps are easy to add to your webpage—just set the URL 
you build as the value of an iframe's src attribute. Control the size of the 
map with the iframe's height and width attributes. No JavaScript required.
```

but I still can't access the link.

Comment: Activate the Google Maps Embed API service.

Comment: And also make sure that enabled "Static Maps API" service also with "Google Maps API" service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Google API key restriction - HTTP referrers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993276/how-to-set-google-api-key-restriction-http-referrers)

Comment: How can this question be a duplicate if it's 3 years older?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem was that they have their "quick start" out of date.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

It says you should only provide them with your API key but the thing is that there is a new version of the same website which they don't have links to from their guide but which you get a link to elsewhere( I got offered when in "billing" )

The new service is called Cloud Console and I found the API on/off buttons there.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/...

You have to enable the "Static Maps API", "Google Maps API" and "Google Maps Embed API" and make sure to have your link in an iframe div

Comment: The key here for me was turning on the Static Maps API, even though I didn't think I was using it (I only had the Google Maps Embed API enabled). Once I turned on the Static API everything kicked into gear.

Comment: For me it worked only after enabling 'Google Places API Web Service'

Answer (score 9):

As Dominik said, go here:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/%your-project-name%/apiui/apis/library?q=google%20maps

Enable both APIs:

- Google Maps Embed API
- Static Maps API

Then go here:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/%your-project-name%/apiui/credential

- Create New Key
- Browser Key

And you're done.

Comment: It's an answer from June of 2015, we are at March 2017.
It's like the accepted answers of froogaloop's integration with vimeo's api,
old.

Best regards Kishan.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to enable the Google Maps JavaScript API.