# uncaught security error blocked a frame

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have imported an iframe in my website but it always gives this problem (see image) , but my iframe does seem to work ...

[image]

Html (the relevant piece) :

```
  <object data="{{songCtrl.googleMapUrl}}" width="600" height="400">
                        <embed ng-src="{{songCtrl.googleMapUrl}}" width="600" height="400"></embed>
                                 Error: De map kon niet worden geladen
                        </object>
```

javascript (the relevant piece):

var app = angular.module('songBoard', []);

```
//whitelist aanpassen: google maps url toevoegen, 
//anders kan deze nt in iframe geopend worden, omdat die als onveilig beschouwd w door angular
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
      $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        // Allow same origin resource loads.
        'self',
        // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
        'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/**'
      ]);
});

app.controller('songController', ['$http', function($http) {

    var songs = this;
    songs.tracks = [];
    songs.youtubeData = [];
    songs.googleMapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=AIzaSyDlcgqT3WT7WlU3R-636TpPEaVEHwqK6Ls&q=";

    $http({
            url: "https://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback"
        })
        .success(function(jsonLastSongsList) {
            songs.tracks = jsonLastSongsList.played_tracks;
            console.log(songs.tracks);
            songs.selectedSong = songs.tracks[0];
            console.log(songs.selectedSong.youtube_ids.default);
            //search(songs.tracks[0].title);                    
            songs.getYoutubeData();
            songs.googleMapUrl += songs.selectedSong.artist.country.name;

        });

    songs.getYoutubeData = function() {


        $http({
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + (songs.selectedSong.youtube_ids.default) 
                + "&key=AIzaSyDlcgqT3WT7WlU3R-636TpPEaVEHwqK6Ls&part=snippet,statistics",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "callback"
            })
            .success(function(jsonYoutubeData) {           
                songs.youtubeData = jsonYoutubeData.items[0];
                console.log(songs.youtubeData);
                songs.youtubeDataList = songs.youtubeData;


            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you opening the page by loading the file directly in chrome instead of a webserver?

Comment: I edited my question to show you the code i used

Comment: Does not answer my original question though

Comment: yes i am opening it with xampp on a local host

Comment: Don't care about the error, it's forced by the iframe, there is nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use google maps simple api on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694049/how-to-use-google-maps-simple-api-on-localhost)