# User rate limit (403 error) with Google AdSense API

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

When making requests to the Google AdSense API I reach the user rate limit. It occurs when three users (different gmail accounts) with access to the same AdSense account are making requests at the same time. I have made sure that one user is only allowed to make 1 request per second and checked in Fiddler that it is actually working.

In the Google API console I find these quota limits:

- Queries per day = 10 000
- Queries per 100 seconds per user = 100
- Queries per 100 seconds = 500

Have anyone else encountered this issue? Also does anyone know if the limit **Queries per 100 seconds** is per application or per account? I can't find any information about it in the API documentation. I am wondering if I might have reached that limit somehow.

Comment: That's weird, I get the same error for all my request made to Google Maps Geocoding API. Today I got 19 call to the api, all of them are 403. And it says that there is a limit of 2500 free api call per day so either there's a bug at google or else I don't know.

Comment: I just digged deap in the plugin I was using to get the real server response with the error and even so the query where showing in the Google console graph as a 403. It's was more about a wrong type of call (I had to create an API specific to call from the server side) Here is the Stack Overflow thread that helped me(https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451277/2018745). If this is the same erreur as mine, hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I happen to run into the same issue.
Adsense management API v1.4 responses:

```
//when the API presumes "Queries per 100 seconds per user" limit breached.
{ 
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded",
      "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"
  }
}
//when the API presumes "Queries per 100 seconds" limit breached.
{ 
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
      "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
  }
}
```

For google, 1+1 requests might not be counted as exactly two. 
You can force produce these limit breaches by reducing your quotas on google developer console.
I advise you to fix your code so that it retries after 2-3 minutes when you hit those limits again.