# How to set API key in ColdFusion for Google Maps geocoding

Tags: coldfusion, google-geocoding-api

Since Google requires recently to add your key to API uses, I have a problem to get it run on a script that was calculating distances properly before. In my code I have this:

```
<cfhttp url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml" method="GET">
```

so if I add the API key like this (according to official documentation):

```
<cfhttp url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=MyKeyGoesHere" method="GET">
```

ColdFusion is telling me there is an error:

> Element GEOCODERESPONSE.RESULT.GEOMETRY.LOCATION.LAT.XMLTEXT is
>   undefined in MYXMLDOC.

I got the same error message, when I tried to add the key via cfhttpparam:

```
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="key" value="MyKeyGoesHere" />
```

Here is the relevant part of the script without API key:

```
<cfset address = '#usersearch#,  DE'>
<cfhttp url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml" method="GET">
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="address" value="#address#" />
<cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="sensor" value="false" />
</cfhttp> 
<cfset myXMLDoc = XMLParse(cfhttp.fileContent) />
<cfif myXMLDoc contains 'ZERO_RESULTS' or myXMLDoc contains 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'>
We have encountered an error, please contact the webmaster
<cfelse>
<cfset latitude = '#myXMLDoc.GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location.lat.XmlText#'>
<cfset longitude = '#myXMLDoc.GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location.lng.XmlText#'>
```

I don't know where else to set the API key...?

Comment: Could you dump the cfhttp response <Cfdump var=#XMLParse(cfhttp.fileContent)#>. I think there is a problem with the restrictions on your api key. The following post may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451277/2482184 . But without more info this is just a guess.

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion?

Comment: It was indeed a restriction problem with the api key like mentioned by @Nebu The response was "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API." I changed it to IP restriction and now the script works fine again. Thank you!