# Google Maps JS API not working in localhost when using MAMP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mamp, custom-wordpress-pages

I am developing a website using WordPress, I am currently in dev stages so using mamp to throw up localhost.

The theme I am using in WP is for real estate agents, and Google Maps in heavily implemented on all the listing pages.  The problem I am running into is that the Google Maps search functionality is not working at all, and it is impossible for me to drag and drop the location to all the listings.[image: Google Maps on Listing Page] [image: error message]

The search functionality is not working on the front end either when I preview the single listing page, it pulls up to Sydney Australia just fine but that is as far as I can get.  When I try to search the properties location in the back end it isn't working

Which lead me to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329874/googlemaps-api-key-for-localhost). which hasn't seemed to work for me.
I am hosting on Apache port 80 so I just use http://localhost and it pulls up the document root that mamp is hosting.  I have tried http://localhost/ , http://localhost/hackBarthRealty/ , and the same variations without the http in the front with no success.
[image: API Application Restrictions]
then I noticed this on the Google Console

[image: Asteriks]
So then I tried the same variations with asterisks on both sides, like so 
*http://localhost/hackbarthRealty* as I am using the map functionality on multiple pages throughout the site and not just one, but these variations didn't work either.

Any input would be good, I'm going a little crazy and starting to think that the Google Maps JS API simply cannot work with my dev environment configuration.

Answer (score 0):

add in your functions.php

```html
wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=enteryourkeyhere&callback=initMap', array(), '', true);
```