# Google Cloud Platform Restrictions Http referrers doesn't work as expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I set the Api Key restrictions to "None", the service works great. If I set the Http referrers to websites, it works as expected with certain websites. If I set the Http referrers to the Urls of Web API Servers, I get a "restricted" message.  Does anyone know how to allow the Url of the Web API Server to make a successful call when restrictions are being used? I would think that api.somedomain.com would work.

Looks like it might not be possible. Wow, what a shame! Hopefully, there is an update or workaround for this.
[How to set Google API key restriction - HTTP referrers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993276/how-to-set-google-api-key-restriction-http-referrers)

By the way, this doesn't work either. This is an example in their documentation.

(*):somedomain.com/*

(*): *.somedomain.com/*

I have to write the full sub domain to all my website Urls.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is creating another Api Key for my Web API Server requests. Since this key isn't displayed in a website, I shouldn't have to lock it down.